# Listing Mapped Network Drives with WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, network-drive

i have an app written in c#, that creates a list of all network drives that are mapped.

I used WMI to achieve this, here is how i did it:

```cs
List < NetworkConnection > networkConnections = new List < NetworkConnection > ();

try {
 var path = new ManagementPath();
 path.NamespacePath = "\\ROOT\\CIMV2";
 path.ClassName = "Win32_NetworkConnection"; //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394220(v=vs.85).aspx

 var management = new ManagementClass(path);

 foreach(ManagementObject obj in management.GetInstances()) {
  NetworkConnection networkConnection = new NetworkConnection() {
   LocalName = (string) obj.Properties["LocalName"].Value,
    Name = (string) obj.Properties["Name"].Value,
    RemotePath = (string) obj.Properties["RemotePath"].Value,
    UserName = (string) obj.Properties["UserName"].Value,
    IsPersistent = (bool) obj.Properties["Persistent"].Value,
    ConnectionState = (string) obj.Properties["ConnectionState"].Value
  };

  networkConnections.Add(networkConnection);
 }
} catch (Exception ex) {
 log.Error($ "Failed to get network connections.", ex);
}

return networkConnections;
```

While this does work on my test clients W7 and W8 64 and 32 bit. It wont work on my W10 clients.
On W10 I just get an emtpy list back.

It looks like management.GetInstances() does not return anything. But why?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where did `NetworkConnection` come from?

Comment: The code works fine on my W10 Win64 using Windows Compatiblity Pack on .Net Core 3 - are you running as an administrator?

Comment: Yes i run this as an admin. I have to. Is this the problem? is there any workaround? @NetMage

Comment: I tested on my Win10 v1809 x64 computer with LINQPad and running locally under admin and as a local administrator it works fine. Is there something special you are doing to run the program (remotely, etc)?